# Uninstall OS X Server completely in Yosemite

Tags: macos, osx-server, administrator

I recently run the OS X Server app on Yosemite. Now each time I shutdown or restart my mac, it asking for administrator password. I don't want to run my MacBook Pro as a server. I ran this app just to test something, now I want to reset to the previous state. Now I feel that there are some daemon process running because of the server app, that slows down my laptop.
How to uninstall or reset all the changes made by OS X Server app on Yosemite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time better test it in a VM or use a Time Machine backup to revert to the previous state.

And here are complete lists of  modified, replaced and added items after starting and quitting Server.app (version 4.1). Depending on any further steps you took there maybe additional items added, modified or replaced.
The lists were compiled with the snapshot feature of [FileBuddy](http://www.skytag.com/filebuddy/en/).

Modified Items:

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
/Library/Logs/LKDC-setup.log
/private/etc/
/private/tftpboot/
/private/tmp/
/private/var/
/private/var/db/
/private/var/jabberd/
/private/var/log/
/private/var/run/
/private/var/tmp/
/private/var/log/accountpolicy.log
/private/var/log/apache2/
/private/var/log/authd.log
/private/var/log/commerce.log
/private/var/log/opendirectoryd.log
/private/var/log/secinitd.log
/private/var/log.log
/private/var/log/powermanagement/StoreData
/private/var/log/module/com.apple.securityd/
/private/var/log/DiagnosticMessages/StoreData
/private/var/log/asl/StoreData
/private/var/db/.configureLocalKDC
/private/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd/
/private/var/db/emondClients/
/private/var/db/locationd/
/private/var/dbstats/
/private/var/dbstats/snapshots.db
/private/var/dbstats/snapshots.db-shm
/private/var/dbstats/snapshots.db-wal
/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/computers/
/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/config/
/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/groups/
/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/sqlindex-wal
/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/
/private/var/db/CoreDuet/coreduetd.db-wal
/private/etc/asl/
/private/etc/krb5.keytab
/private/etc/newsyslog.d/
/private/etc/paths.d/
/private/etc/pf.anchors/
/private/etc/pf.conf
/private/etc/shells
/private/etc/syslog.conf
/private/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple
/private/etc/emond.d/emond.plist
/usr/lib/php/
```

Replaced Items:

```
/Library/PreferencesConfiguration/preferences.plist
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.AppleFileServer.plist
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.networkextension.plist
/Library/Keychains.keychain
/Library/PreferencesConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server.plist
/private/etc/ssh_config
/private/etc/sshd_config
/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/_krbtgt.plist
/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/_krbfast.plist
/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/computers/localhost.plist
/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/groups/_appserveradm.plist
/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/groups/_appserverusr.plist
/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/_teamsserver.plist
/private/etc/asl/com.apple.mail
/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/root.plist
/private/var/db/locationd/clients.plist
/usr/sbin/sendmail
```

New Items (if the line ends with a slash the whole directory and all subitems/subdirectories are added: e.g. /System/Library/Logs/ProfileManager/ or /System/private/tmp/pear/):

```
/.ServerBackups
/Applications/Server.app
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.serverd.plist
/Library/Logs/EventMonitor/
/Library/Logs/Mail/
/Library/Logs/PostgreSQL/
/Library/Logs/ProfileManager/
/Library/Logs/radiusconfig.log
/Library/Logs/Server
/Library/Logs/servermgr_xcode.log
/Library/Logs/ServerSetup.log
/Library/Logs/Setup.log
/Library/Logs/WebServer
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.AccountsConfigServer.plist
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.servermgr_accounts.plist
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.servermgr_calendar.plist
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.servermgrd.plist
/Library/PreferencesConfiguration/autodiskmount.plist
/Library/PreferencesConfiguration/com.apple.RemoteAccessServers.plist
/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd
/Library/Server/
/private/etc/af.plist
/private/etc/asl/com.apple.mail.push_notify
/private/etc/asl/com.apple.server.asl
/private/etc/asl/com.apple.server.servermgrd.log
/private/etc/asl/com.apple.servermetricsd
/private/etc/bootpd.plist
/private/etc/certificates/
/private/etc/newsyslog.d/com.apple.devicemgr.conf
/private/etc/newsyslog.d/com.apple.mailservices.conf
/private/etc/newsyslog.d/servermgr_calendar_log.conf
/private/etc/paths.d/com.apple.server
/private/etc/pear.conf
/private/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple.server-firewall
/private/etc/php.ini
/private/etc/php.ini-5.5-previous
/private/etc/rc.server
/private/tftpboot/NetBoot/
/private/tmp/pear/
/private/var/db/.ServerSetupDone
/private/var/db/af/
/private/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd/disabled.220.plist
/private/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd/disabled.94.plist
/private/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd/loginitems.220.plist
/private/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd/loginitems.94.plist
/private/var/db/dovecot.fts.update/
/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/config/dhcp.plist
/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/config/shadowhash.plist
/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/groups/com.apple.access_default-disabled.plist
/private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/com.apple.calendarserver.plist
/private/var/db/emondClients/com.apple.server
/private/var/db/net-snmp/
/private/var/dovecot/
/private/var/jabberd/log/
/private/var/log/apache2/access_log
/private/var/log/apache2/error_log
/private/var/log/devicemgr
/private/var/log/eventmonitor/
/private/var/log/mail.log
/private/var/log/radius/
/private/var/log/servermetricsd/
/private/var/pgsql_socket/State/com.apple.Server.v4.savedState/
/private/var/run/caldavd/
/private/var/run/com.apple.xpc.smd/
/private/var/run/jabberd/
/private/var/run/kick-collabpp/
/private/var/servermgrd/
/usr/bin/pear
/usr/bin/peardev
/usr/bin/pecl
/usr/lib/php/.channels/
/usr/lib/php/.depdb
/usr/lib/php/.depdblock
/usr/lib/php/.filemap
/usr/lib/php/.lock
/usr/lib/php/.registry/
/usr/lib/php/Archive/
/usr/lib/php/Console/
/usr/lib/php/data/
/usr/lib/php/doc/
/usr/lib/php/OS/
/usr/lib/php/PEAR.php
/usr/lib/php/PEAR/
/usr/lib/php/pearcmd.php
/usr/lib/php/peclcmd.php
/usr/lib/php/Structures/
/usr/lib/php.php
/usr/lib/php/test/
/usr/lib/php/XML/
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.servermgrd.plugin/
~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.serveralertproxy.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Server.v4.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.serveralertproxy.plist
```

Comment: Your /Library/Keychains.keychain item in the replaced list, should be /Library/Keychains/System.keychain as Server adds several identities & password items to the System keychain.

Answer (score 7):

I got this solution by posting the same on apple discussion forum. I wanted to post the answer here because, it might help someone else. Many thanks to the friend who gave me this solution.

Move the Server application to the Trash. Delete the following items (some may not exist), then reboot:

```
/.ServerBackups
/var/db/.ServerSetupDone
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.serverd.plist
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.servermgr_accounts.plist
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.servermgr_certs.plist
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.servermgr_info.plist
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.servermgrd.plist
/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd
/Library/Server
```

Here's [Apple Discussion forum link](https://discussions.apple.com/message/28002107#28002107)

Comment: After removing those directories to uninstall Server I was getting this error when running `sendmail`: 
`sendmail: fatal: open /Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory`
To fix this, edit `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and remove the line `config_directory = /Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix`. Or change it back to `server_config_directory = /etc/postfix`. Then it'll use the configs in `/etc/postfix` again instead of the now non-existent configs from OSX Server.