# How can I remove the OSX server?

Tags: macos, osx-server

I have installed a OSX server a long time ago for testing purpose. It shows up in my App Store

[image]

However I cannot install update on my iMac that's running El Capitan due to this error message:

[image]

I really want to remove it because apparently this package is preventing me upgrade to Sierra. Sierra installer requested this to be of latest version before proceeding any further.

Comment: Related: [Uninstall OS X Server completely in Yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/178959/uninstall-os-x-server-completely-in-yosemite)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an admin, open the /Applications folder, and drag the Server.app icon to the trash. An alert should pop up, saying the the server will be shut down, and a bunch of uninstall scripts will run. Your data will still be in /Library/Server.

You can empty the trash or pull it back out, if you want to keep it.

Then you should be able to upgrade the OS in peace.

Answer (score 5):

*@Leland Wallace answer is completely correct to "remove" macOS Server but here is how to completely remove everything related to macOS Server.*

**Note:** This will remove all data relevant, including, but not limited to, Web Site files, Wiki Files, Configuration Files. This will basically leave your computer as it was before you installed macOS Server.

1. Right click on the Server Application and click "Show Package Contents"
2. Navigate to `/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/devicemgr/backend`
3. Double click on `wipeDB.sh`. This should open it in terminal.
4. Enter your admin password (or root password if setup)
5. Alternately: in terminal: `sudo ./Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/devicemgr/backend/wipeDB.sh`
6. Then follow @Leland Wallace answer and remove the Server application